# snowflake shows at the beginning of boot and reboot a ubuntu 2204 VM on Xen (Only UEFI/Secure boot)

Tags: boot, drivers, uefi, display, xen

The boot process below includes a step displaying a snowflake, which is not present in the BIOS boot process.